# static std::atomic<foo *> bar[CONSTANT_BAZ], is it initialized or not?

Tags: arrays, c++11, stdatomic

I have an array of atomic pointers at global scope. Are these initialized to nullptr, or is it necessary to do this by hand, e.g.

```
// Found a reason to use double-braces, but is it needed??
static std::atomic<foo *> bar[CONSTANT_BAZ] {{nullptr}};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

atomics are treated as built-in types (to be more precise, they have a trivial [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic)) and as such, a global array of them will automatically be zero initialized to `nullptr`.

Only in the local case, you'd have to initialize it manually, but even then, you don't have to use double braces or `nullptr`. This would suffice:

```
void baz() {
    std::atomic<foo *> bar[CONSTANT_BAZ]{};
}
```